# Unity - Scroll view gets stuck while scrolling too fast

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a parallax scroll-and-snap scroll view on a iOS iPhone game(a duplicate of the game Arknights) in unity. But sometimes(not always) when I swipe too fast, the scroll view gets stuck between 2 elements of the scroll view. In the video which shows this error, I started swiping very fast until the error occurs, then I swiped slowly, one by one, to see the error clearly. Any ideas on how to solve this?
My script that are relevant are as follows(please tell me if more is needed~):

Video showing the error:https://youtu.be/tSrRG3kdpnA

```
 void LerpTargetPos()
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
        StartCoroutine(LerpTargetPosCoroutine());
    }
    IEnumerator LerpTargetPosCoroutine()
    {
        if (scrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition != targetPos)
        {
            scrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition = Mathf.Lerp(scrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition, targetPos, lerpSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Mathf.Abs(scrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition - targetPos) <= 0.0005f)
        {
            scrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition = targetPos;
        }
        yield return null;
    }
```

```
if (canLerp)
  {
      LerpTargetPos();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok – turns out I put the `LerpTargetPos` method in the `LateUpdate` method, instead of `Update`; after I put it in `Update`, everything seems to work fine.